# getting router confuguration page instead of my web home page of my website

Tags: apache, web-hosting

I am trying to host a website from my local pc. For that i have installed apache server, registered a domain name and done the necessary settings.The problem is that when I am trying to access my homepage I am getting the router configuration page, same is happening when I am trying to access the website from other computer.Please help.

Answer (score 0):

When hosting a website from a local PC behind a router you need to be careful to use the public IP that your service provider has given you. Beware this is often not a static address and may change frequently. To address this you can use some type of DynDNS service if your router supports it.

Second, you will need to add a rule in your router's firewall to allow the traffic from the public internet to reach the computer behind the router. This can be done either with a DMZ (less secure) or a port forwarding.

When you are trying to access the web page, type in the local ip of the computer you have setup the server on. This should take you to the apache server. You are likely just typing in the wrong IP. Try something like http://127.0.0.1/ (127.0.0.1 is the same as localhost) to make sure you get the apache server from the computer that is running the server.

Comment: Thanks Kevin,with http://127.0.0.1 I am able to connect to apache server.I am trying with port forwarding.Is installing router and server on same port 80 causing issue?

Comment: I tried port forwarding ,by redirecting external port 80 to internal ip  192.168.1.2 port 8080 .I have also changed apache server settings to listen port 8080 .But still I am getting the same issue.

Comment: It might be that your ISP is blocking traffic on port 80. Some ISPs don't allow you to host web servers and may be blocking inbound traffic on that port.